# Inbox Reader - Reads your inbox

Tags: app, inbox

### Screenshot

[image]

### About

It reads your inbox

#### License

Inbox Reader is released under the [Apache License 2.0](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/Apache-2.0).

#### Download

You can download Inbox Reader here:
http://teamfreehugs.github.io/stackexchange/inboxreader/clean.html

### Contact

I can be reached at `eyeballcode@gmail.com`.

### Code

Inbox Reader is written in html, javascript.

The code can be retrieved from here:
https://github.com/TeamFreeHugs/teamfreehugs.github.io/blob/master/stackexchange/inboxreader/clean.html

### Note

You can use this as an addon for web browsers, like this:
[image]